# jQuery passing variabile to .css({})

Tags: jquery, css, variables

I have the following function:

```
$("#myId").css({left: leftVal+"px", top:topVal+"px"});
```

this works.

I am looking for a way to add `left: leftVal+"px", top:topVal+"px"` as a variable and make my function:

```
$("#myId").css({myCSSstuff});
```

I've tryed

```
var myCSSstuff= "left: "+leftVal+"px, top:"+topVal+"px"
```

but it does not work.
Is there a way to do this?
Thanx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var myCSSstuff = { left: leftVal, top: topVal };
$("#myId").css(myCSSstuff);
```

The `{}` notation is for objects or associative arrays.

There are two ways you can add more properties:

```
myCSSstuff.color = 'red';
myCSSstuff['color'] = 'red';
```

The second approach allows you to use strings for the property name, i.e.

```
var prop = 'color';
myCSSstuff[prop] = 'red';
```

Comment: and you can omit the `'px'` part. (jquery handles that automatically)

Comment: thanx, this works!. What if I need to add another variable in the array at some point. Something like myCSSstuff = myCSSstuff + {color: something}. How can I do that? Thanx again